# Adding classname to Colorbox dynamically

Tags: jquery, function, colorbox

I've seen questions regarding this issue on here already, but I'm having a different issue trying to get it to work.

With the following code I want to add a classname to the colorbox lightbox once it has opened.

For some reason though the second function (where .addclass is executed) does not work (when I inspect the code in firebug it doesn't even enter that function).

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".box1").colorbox(function(){
                $("#colorbox").addClass("box1");
            });
        });
```

Is it something I'm missing or am I trying to do this incorrectly?

Thanks Ian

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Newer versions of Colorbox support the new [className setting](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/#setting-className) which can be used to add extra class names to colorbox.

---

**Original answer:**

You need to specify the onOpen callback for colorbox like this:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $(".box1").colorbox({onOpen: function(){
           $("#colorbox").addClass("box1");
       }});
   });
```

There's also an option to listen for the `cbox_open` event instead of using a callback - see http://jacklmoore.com/colorbox/ for more information.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! The callback is what I'm after for now as I want to call colorbox from 3 different elements on the page and add a different classname for each colorbox. I'm sure I could make it more elegant with event listening, but will look into that later.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, as per the EventHook section on ColorBox.

```
$(document).bind('cbox_complete', function(){
    $("#colorbox").addClass("box1");
});
```

Answer (score 3):

This will do the trick, it's a new attribute:

```
$('.my-box').colorbox({className: 'my-class'});
```